# Ionic 4 horizontal scroll with ngFor

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ngfor, ionic4

I'm at a loss.  I can get horizontal scroll to work fine with just html and css but when i introduce ngFor, it refuses to produce the same effect..  Does anyone have experience with this, or know how to solve the issue?

here is my simple code that does not work:

this example yields a vertical list:

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
        <div class="scroll" scrollX="true">
         <span>{{item.ProjectEvent}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this one yields a wide container that scrolls horizontally

```
 <div class="container" >
        <div class="scroll" scrollX="true">
            <span>item1</span>
            <span>item2</span>
            <span>item3</span>
            <span>item4</span>
            <span>item5</span>
            <span>item6</span>
            <span>item7</span>
            <span>item8</span>
            <span>item9</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the same css for both:

```
.container {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
  .scroll {
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
```

Explain that one to me Mr. Spock!

Thanks for the help in advance!

Dependencies for good measure:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "^7.1.4",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.21",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0-beta.21",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0-beta.21",
    "@ionic/angular": "4.0.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.8.0",
    "ngx-navigation-with-data": "^1.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using the directive on the actual element that needs to get replicated:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="scroll" scrollX="true">
        <span *ngFor="let item of items | async">{{item.ProjectEvent}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that actually does give me a horizontally rendered list, which is a step in the right direction!  but the list wraps to the next line instead of moving off screen and scrolling.

Comment: Never mind, that actually did it!!  i had commented out the "container" css.  Thanks so much Sergey!

Answer (score 10):

Using flexbox:

```
div[scrollx=true] {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
     display: none;
  }
   .scroll-item {
     flex: 0 0 auto;
  }
}
```

https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-horizontal-scrolling-containers-d8069651e9c6

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try it

```
<ion-segment scrollable="true">
    <ion-segment-button value="friends">
      <ion-label>Friends</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

Comment: This should be the solution but at the time of writing the scroll is only works with shift+scroll in PWA mode, which is very unintuitive